# Compare all columns between two sheets based on a unique identifier column and update Sheet1 rows if difference exists

Tags: vba, excel

I have a workbook that has 2 worksheets and sub-sheets Named as per Product Line Column:

- NEW DATA sheet
- Master Table sheet ("DBQ Query Result")
- Subsheets (Driling and Workover, Fishing, Liner Systems, Professional Services, Wellbore Cleaning)

They both have same headers, within the column headers there is a uniqueID column.

#### PART A

I would like to match uniqueID between those 2 sheets and:

- When there is a match, compare row cell values for each column and update if there is difference
- When there is a uniqueID in NEW DATA sheet that does not exist in Master Table, I would like this whole row associated to this uniqueId to be copied to Master Table sheet

#### PART B

I would like to have a new button that when pressed, UniqueID from Master Page will be compared with Unique Id column of each subsheet and:

- When there is a match, update subsheet row according to UNIQUEID
- When there is no match, that means a new UNIQUEID is created and this should be added to its corresponding subsheet as a last row

I would like to accomplish the above using VBA macro please. I have attached a sample of the excel https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29585269/Sample.xlsx.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I'm not sure I understand your problem statement. When you say "sub-sheets", what does that mean? (Inside the linked worksheet, I do not see a worksheet named "sub-sheets" or "Subsheets".) Additionally, the linked sheet does not include a worksheet named "Master Table". Can you please clarify?

Comment: Hi dan, thanks for your reply. My mistake, Master Sheet is "DBQ Query Result" and subsheets are regular sheets that came from Product Line Column which are Driling and Workover, Fishing, Liner Systems,Professional Services, Wellbore Cleaning

Answer (score 1):

I came across few codes online and modified them to fit my need.

So, this is how it goes:

You have 3 Main Sheets next to your PL Sheets - Subsheets (Driling and Workover, Fishing, Liner Systems, Professional Services, Wellbore Cleaning):

- Original
- Updated
- Changes

This code will print the changes between Original Sheet and Updated Sheet:

```
Option Explicit

    Sub CompareSheets()
        '
        ' constants
        '  worksheets & ranges
        '   original
        Const ksWSOriginal = "ORIGINAL"
        Const ksOriginal = "OriginalTable"
        Const ksOriginalKey = "OriginalKey"
        '   updated
        Const ksWSUpdated = "UPDATED"
        Const ksUpdated = "UpdatedTable"
        Const ksUpdatedKey = "UpdatedKey"
        '   changes
        Const ksWSChanges = "CHANGES"
        Const ksChanges = "ChangesTable"
        '  labels
        Const ksChange = "CHANGE"
        Const ksRemove = "REMOVE"
        Const ksAdd = "ADD"
        '
        ' declarations
        Dim rngO As Range, rngOK As Range, rngU As Range, rngUK As Range, rngC As Range
        Dim c As Range
        Dim I As Long, J As Long, lChanges As Long, lRow As Long, bEqual As Boolean
        '
        ' start
        Set rngO = Worksheets(ksWSOriginal).Range(ksOriginal)
        Set rngOK = Worksheets(ksWSOriginal).Range(ksOriginalKey)
        Set rngU = Worksheets(ksWSUpdated).Range(ksUpdated)
        Set rngUK = Worksheets(ksWSUpdated).Range(ksUpdatedKey)
        Set rngC = Worksheets(ksWSChanges).Range(ksChanges)
        With rngC
            If .Rows.Count > 1 Then
                Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(.Rows.Count)).ClearContents
                Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(.Rows.Count)).Font.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexAutomatic
                Range(.Rows(2), .Rows(.Rows.Count)).Font.Bold = False
            End If
        End With
        '
        ' process
        lChanges = 1
        '  1st pass: updates & deletions
        With rngOK
            For I = 5 To .Rows.Count
                Set c = rngUK.Find(.Cells(I, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    ' deletion
                    lChanges = lChanges + 1
                    rngC.Cells(lChanges, 1).Value = ksRemove
                    For J = 1 To rngO.Columns.Count
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngO.Cells(I, J).Value
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Color = vbRed
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Bold = True
                    Next J
                Else
                    bEqual = True
                    lRow = c.Row - rngUK.Row + 1
                    For J = 1 To rngO.Columns.Count
                        If rngO.Cells(I, J).Value <> rngU.Cells(lRow, J).Value Then
                            bEqual = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next J
                    If Not bEqual Then
                        ' change
                        lChanges = lChanges + 1
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, 1).Value = ksChange
                        For J = 1 To rngO.Columns.Count
                            If rngO.Cells(I, J).Value = rngU.Cells(lRow, J).Value Then
                                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngO.Cells(I, J).Value
                            Else
                                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngU.Cells(I, J).Value
                                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Color = vbMagenta
                                rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Bold = True
                            End If
                        Next J
                    End If
                End If
            Next I
        End With
        '  2nd pass: additions
        With rngUK
            For I = 5 To .Rows.Count
                Set c = rngOK.Find(.Cells(I, 1).Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                If c Is Nothing Then
                    ' addition
                    lChanges = lChanges + 1
                    rngC.Cells(lChanges, 1).Value = ksAdd
                    For J = 1 To rngU.Columns.Count
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Value = rngU.Cells(I, J).Value
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Color = vbBlue
                        rngC.Cells(lChanges, J + 1).Font.Bold = True
                    Next J
                End If
            Next I
        End With
        '
        ' end
        Worksheets(ksWSChanges).Activate
        rngC.Cells(2, 3).Select
        Set rngC = Nothing
        Set rngUK = Nothing
        Set rngU = Nothing
        Set rngOK = Nothing
        Set rngO = Nothing
        Beep
        '
    End Sub
```

This Button Code will Apply Updates to rows noted as "Changes" and "Add" (I dont care about Remove)

```
    Sub Update()

    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim tempName As String
    Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
    Dim s2Row As Long, s1Row As Long
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORIGINAL")
    Set sh2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("CHANGES")

    lastRow1 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    'Get last row for both sheets
    lastRow2 = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row    ' searching both

    For s2Row = 2 To lastRow2                              'Loop through "CHANGES"
        If sh2.Cells(s2Row, 1).Value = "CHANGE" Then
            tempName = sh2.Cells(s2Row, 2).Value           'extra step for understanding concept
                                                           'There is a match, so now
            For s1Row = 2 To lastRow1                      'Search through the other sheet
                If sh1.Cells(s1Row, 1).Value = tempName Then
                    For I = 2 To 35
                        sh1.Cells(s1Row, I).Value = sh2.Cells(s2Row, I + 1).Value    'Copy Values
                    Next I
                End If
            Next s1Row
        End If
    Next s2Row

    For s2Row = 2 To lastRow2
        If sh2.Cells(s2Row, 1).Value = "ADD" Then
                    sh2.Range("B" & s2Row & ":BB" & s2Row).Copy         'Copy rows
                    sh1.Rows(lastRow1 + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown         'Insert rows
                    sh1.Cells(lastRow1 + 1, 78).Value = "ADD"            'Classify the row as newly added
        End If
    Next s2Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Sheets("ORIGINAL").Activate
    End Sub
```

And this button will apply updates to PL Cell Values for existing UniqueIDs changes

```
    Sub Update_PL()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim lastRng As Range
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'speed up code

        'Added to loop through all UniqueIDs and update accordingly
        Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet
        Dim tempName As String
        Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
        Dim s2Row As Long, s1Row As Long

        'No Longer requires clearing screen, we will match unique ids and update/add as necessary
        'ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORIGINAL").Rows("5:65536").ClearContents 'clear

        Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORIGINAL") 'Define Master Table
        Set sh2 = ws                                    'Selects Active Sheet

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            Set lastRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORIGINAL").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            Select Case ws.Name
            Case "ORIGINAL" 'exlude
            Case "UPDATED" 'exlude
            Case "CHANGES" 'exlude
            Case "Report Table" 'exlude
            Case "DASHBOARD" 'exlude
                 'do nothing
            Case Else
                ws.Activate
                    lastRow2 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                              'Count Master Table Rows to extract Last Row #
                    With ActiveSheet
                        lastRow1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                  'Count Active Sheet Rows to extract Last Row #
                    End With
                For s2Row = 2 To lastRow2                                                            'Loop through Active WorkSheet
                        tempName = sh1.Cells(s2Row, 1).Value                                         'Define UniqueID to loop
                        tempPL = sh1.Cells(s2Row, 22).Value                                          'Define PL to loop
                        For s1Row = 2 To lastRow1                                                    'Match UniqueIDs between Master sheet and Active Sheet
                            If ActiveSheet.Cells(s1Row, 1).Value = tempName Then                     'If Matches TRUE then
                                For I = 2 To 35                                                      'Loop all Columns and update as necessary
                                    ActiveSheet.Cells(s1Row, I).Value = sh1.Cells(s2Row, I).Value    'Copy Values
                                Next I
                            End If
                        Next s1Row
                Next s2Row

                 'copy data from individual sheets
                 'Range("A2", Range("AB65536").End(xlUp)).Copy lastRng

            End Select
        Next
        Application.CutCopyMode = False 'clear clipboard
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Sheets("ORIGINAL").Activate
    End Sub
```

And this last button is used to Add new UniqueIDs to corresponding PL

```
    Sub Add_Rows()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim lastRng As Range
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'speed up code

        'Added to loop through all UniqueIDs and update accordingly
        Dim sh1 As Worksheet
        Dim tempPL As String
        Dim lastRow1 As Long, lastRow2 As Long
        Dim s2Row As Long, s1Row As Long

        Set sh1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ORIGINAL") 'Define Master Table

        For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            Set lastRng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("ORIGINAL").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

            Select Case ws.Name
            Case "ORIGINAL" 'exlude
            Case "UPDATED" 'exlude
            Case "CHANGES" 'exlude
            Case "Report Table" 'exlude
            Case "DASHBOARD" 'exlude
                 'do nothing
            Case Else
                ws.Activate
                    lastRow2 = sh1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                              'Count Master Table Rows to extract Last Row #
                    With ActiveSheet
                        lastRow1 = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row                  'Count Active Sheet Rows to extract Last Row #
                    End With

                For s2Row = 5 To lastRow2                                                            'Loop through Active WorkSheet
                        If sh1.Cells(s2Row, 78).Value = "ADD" Then
                            tempPL = sh1.Cells(s2Row, 23).Value
                                If ActiveSheet.Name = tempPL Then
                                        sh1.Range("A" & s2Row & ":AB" & s2Row).Copy                      'Copy rows
                                        ActiveSheet.Rows(lastRow1 + 1).Insert Shift:=xlDown              'Insert rows
                                        sh1.Cells(s2Row, 78).Value = "ADDED"                      'Validate Row has been added in Master Sheet
                                End If
                        End If
                Next s2Row

            End Select

        Next
            Application.CutCopyMode = False     'clear clipboard
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True   'Resume ScreenUpdating
            Sheets("ORIGINAL").Activate         'Display Original Sheet

    End Sub
```

Complicated? Yeah... but solved my issue.

BR! Eddy